# How can I prevent recyclerview paymentlist continue add their list?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

when I clicked orderProduct btn over 1times, layout showed 2 paymentlist. 
How can I solve this situation?

```
 orderProduct.setOnClickListener {

        orderProduct.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                0,
                0,
                if (!isClicked) R.drawable.btn_down else R.drawable.btn_up,
                0
            )
            if (isClicked) {
                val layout = findViewById(R.id.orderRecyclerview) as RecyclerView
                val itemRecyclerAdapter = PaymentRecylcerViewAdapter(this, paymentlist)
                paymentlist.add(PaymentItemDataVo("bottle", 1, 29990))
                orderRecyclerview.adapter = itemRecyclerAdapter
                orderRecyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
                layout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                val layout = findViewById(R.id.orderRecyclerview) as RecyclerView
                layout.visibility = View.GONE
            }
            isClicked = !isClicked
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if paymentlist already have elements. If it has then clear the list before inserting elements and loading.